# Scraping a download button without a hyperlink R

Tags: r

I am trying to scrape CPI data from the following website https://beta.bls.gov/dataViewer/view by clicking on the 'csv' button. All my code is done through R

I usually would pass through the hyper-link associated with the csv button on the webpage but when I right click the button, there is no url.

I have tried a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366491/how-to-use-r-to-download-a-file-from-webpage-when-there-is-no-specific-file-embe/56367795) post but my code gets stuck on the part where I create the 'driver' object (error below)

```
library(RSelenium)
library(here)

  url <- "https://beta.bls.gov/dataViewer/view"
  
  button_id <- "csvclickCU" #csvclickCU.csvclick.dq-button
  
  filename <- "CPU.csv"
  
  download_location <- getwd()
  
  driver <- rsDriver(
    browser = "chrome",
    chromever = "88.0.4324.150"
  )
```

Error in chrome_ver(chromecheck[["platform"]], chromever) :
version requested doesnt match versions available = 88.0.4324.27,88.0.4324.96,89.0.4389.23

I've tried to pass one of those available versions that is offered in the Error, into the 'chromever' argument of 'driver'. and the code will execute but it then gets stuck on

```
server <- driver$server
  browser <- driver$client
  
  buttons <- list()
  browser$navigate(url)
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator no I didnt

Comment: I think you need to use rselenium as I too have a similar issue and that’s what I’ve been seeing as answers