# Download data from “click download button” on a webpage with R

Tags: r, web, download

I am trying to load data from a webpage in R, which requires button-clicking to accomplish that. I just spent hours navigating to similar Stack Overflow questions, but I did not manage.
[This here, for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366491/how-to-use-r-to-download-a-file-from-webpage-when-there-is-no-specific-file-embe/56367795).

There is an R package for downloading such data `GetTDData`, but it does not allow downloading data from a specific year. Obviously, I could filter after getting the data, but it takes a lot of time, so selecting only the data for the current year would save important time.

Below is the link from where I try to download the data.
Any of the data (for example `"LFT_2021.xls"`) would be fantastic so that I can learn to download the rest (e.g. LFT_2021.xls)

https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/historico-de-precos-e-taxas.htm

Comment: It is possible, but not very simple. I would suggest looking at other ways of retrieving the data. Have you looked at https://github.com/msperlin/GetTDData?. If the package does not work because it has not been updated in the last two years, you can try to adapt the download function from https://github.com/msperlin/GetTDData/blob/master/R/gtdd_download_TD_data.R

Comment: That is a good point. The R package works fine, but it downloads the entire time series, which makes the processing time costly.  I want to use the data in an App so I would like to download the data only from the current year. I will try to modify the package to accomplish that.

Comment: pois é. it wouldn't be too hard to modify the function and include year range as an argument or hard code only the last year. If you feel it is unlike that this question and comments will be helpful to others, consider closing this question, if no one else comes up with a "better answer" :)

Comment: Beleza! I got it done, thanks a lot for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found many ways to get the data, but the easiest method was the following:

I *right_clicked* the download icon in the webpage and copied the link from there.
Basically, I used the  `download.file()` function to download the data in a specific directory. Very easy.

`url_link <- paste0("https://apiapex.tesouro.gov.br/aria/", "v1/sistd/custom/historico?ano=2021&idSigla=1")`

`download.file(url = url_link, destfile = "Downloads/file_name.xls")`